# Does Rocket have something like Flask's blueprints?

Tags: rust, rust-rocket

In Python's Flask, there is a feature called blueprints, SO even got a [great overview](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24420857/what-are-flask-blueprints-exactly) of it. Does Rocket have something similar, so I can better structure my code and not mount each route in *main*?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Rocket has something called route mounting where you can mount a list of subroutes on a given path the documentation for the same can be found at https://rocket.rs/v0.4/guide/overview/#mounting